# In Gtk, is it possible to make widgets fade in and out?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#, clutter

I would like to have a `Label` (or at least the text on the label) do a quick fade-in. It looks like this is [possible in clutter](http://blog.didrocks.fr/index.php/post/Design-experience-and-demos-in-GTK-Clutter), but I don't want to use clutter until clutter-sharp is packaged for Ubuntu. Is there any way to do this that doesn't involve using clutter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `gtk_widget_get_snapshot()` and then fade out the GdkPixmap it returns using cairo

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen it in any of the more common GTK themes, but Google Chrome's new theme does this, and it uses GTK. So, I'm going to say yes, but not many use it.